# How to Unit test the rendering of a child component in the parent component using react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

I cannot post the original code here ,so i will try to explain what i want to achieve.
So,my component displays message.This message is part of a child component which is being rendered in the parent component.So,i want to unit test this logic.But i don't know how to write the unit test for rendering of child component in react testing library.Example code:

```
function Home(props){
const message=props;
if(message==='warning')
return <Warning display={message}/>
```

So i want to write unit test to achieve this rendering of warning component in my parent component using react-testing-library.

Comment: let me know if my answer helps or if you need any more help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see your code so I'm kind of guessing but you need something like this:

```
const props = { message: 'warning'}

const { container, getByText } = render(
    <Home {...props} />,
)

expect(getByText('warning')).toBeInTheDocument()
```

let me know if that works

Comment: I can't find toBeInTheDocument() method.I am missing something??

Comment: what are you importing from `react-testing-library`? you need to import: `import { render } from '@testing-library/react'` and then it should be on the page already

Comment: I have imported it in the same manner as suggested by you.But still it's not in the page.

Comment: i figured it out.i need to import' import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'.Let me test if your solution works.

Comment: what are you importing now?

Comment: ah ok yes. is that all fixed then?

Comment: Yes this works.But I have another question for you .This time i want to check the rendering of a child componenet which just displays loading icon on UI.How can i do that??

Comment: please accept the answer if it works with the tick to indicate to others it is complete! I can up vote your question too :) (if you need more help feel free to ask another question)

Comment: @CodeOfLife if you ask another question and tag me in it, I will answer :)